# Arrays in AJAX request JSON object data

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I am sending a request to a Node/Express server using jQuery thats data is a JSON object containing an array:

```
var data = {
    "name": "James Jamesy",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Tiny James",
            "age": "4"
        },
        {
            "name": "Little James",
            "age": "6"
        },
        {
            "name": "Graham",
            "age": "8"
        }
    ]
}

var request = $.ajax({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: apiPath + 'updateuser',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

The request itself is working fine, however the server is reporting the data as:

```
{ 
    name: 'James Jamesy',
    'children[0][name]': 'Little James',
    'children[0][age]': '4',
    'children[1][name]': 'Medium James',
    'children[1][age]': '6',
    'children[2][name]': 'Graham',
    'children[2][age]': '8'
}
```

Now I've figured out that I can get my desired result by instead stringifying the children array:

```
var data = {
    "name": "James Jamesy",
    "children": JSON.stringify([ ... ])
}
```

And then `JSON.parse()`ing it on the server.

However I am hoping someone can explain *why* the array is converted as it is in the request, and whether I should be handling this a different way? As in this instance converting the single array is fine, but going forward I might have semi-complex objects I'm looking to send to the server.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Additionally and *strangely*(?), if I send the JSON result back as the passed JSON, it works perfectly:

```
res.json(JSON.parse(req.body.categories));
```

The browser logs out the object and I can manipulate it perfectly fine.

Comment: Try changing `dataType: 'json'` to `contentType: 'json'` in the ajax call

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately this results in the server simply receiving an empty object. (`{}`)

Comment: I see a lot of JSON mistakes lol Are you using body parser in Express?

Comment: Since `children` is an array of objects, you will see `children[0]` to refer to the first entry, `children[1]` for the second entry. And then using bracket notation to add the properties seems like the way it is working to add properties to each of those array entries - `children[0][name]` is at least somewhat looking like bracket notation, although it's a little confusing because normally you would see `children[0]["name"]` in that case? So it is a little confusing as to what is happening.

Comment: @LuisEstevez I'm working in someone else's framework, and just had a look and it does appear that it's using `body-parser`. Could this be what's causing the behaviour?

Comment: @stuntboots res.json returns the json as string. that's why its undoing your JSON.parse. Read more: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L229

Comment: @LuisEstevez The res.json works fine, I can use it straight away on the client. It's the sending an array to the server that seems to be behaving strangely.

Comment: @stuntboots add `contentType: 'application/json'` and `data: JSON.stringify(data)` and by the way with json body parser you don't need to parse req.body... it's already parsed

Comment: @LuisEstevez Hey, that worked perfectly! I had to parse it prior to these changes, as it was just coming in as a string. But adding `contentType: 'application/json'` and then `JSON.stringify`ing the whole object has it running properly! If you post it as an answer I can mark it as correct?

Comment: @stuntboots Great! I'm happy it worked for you. I added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You weren't passing a JSON string through ajax which is why you couldn't handle the data on the back end.

```
var data = {
    "name": "James Jamesy",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Tiny James",
            "age": "4"
        },
        {
            "name": "Little James",
            "age": "6"
        },
        {
            "name": "Graham",
            "age": "8"
        }
    ]
}

var request = $.ajax({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: apiPath + 'updateuser',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType: 'application/json', // for request
    dataType: 'json' // for response
});
```